# Invalid character found in the request target

Tags: internet-explorer, jakarta-ee, xmlhttprequest, tomcat7

I have a problem with a J2EE web app, I need to be able to modify a content of a cell and save the modification in the database, I found the solution on Chrome with contenteditable and XMLHttpRequest but this solution doesn't seem to work on internet explorer whenever I try to save the modification I get this error:

```
INFOS: Error parsing HTTP request header
Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.parseRequestLine(InternalInputBuffer.java:189)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1028)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
...
```

the function that gets the modification to save it in the database is:

```
function MajFD(id_table, compteur){
                    var nouvelleValeur = document.getElementById('descFD' + compteur).innerHTML.replace(/&lt;br\s*\/&gt;/g,'<br/>');
                    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhttp.open("GET","<%=request.getContextPath()%>/action/UpdateDesc.action?id_table=" + id_table + " &nouvelleDescription=" 
                            +  nouvelleValeur, true);
                    valuesFD[compteur] = nouvelleValeur;
                    xhttp.send();
                    document.getElementById('ModifierFD' + compteur).setAttribute('style','display: none;');
                    document.getElementById('cancelFD' + compteur).setAttribute('style','display: none;');
                }
```

Comment: Apply proper URL encoding to the values you put into the URL. (Please research how to do this in JavaScript, if this means nothing to you.)

Comment: In fact this isn't a code I wrote myslef I was just asked to corret the "bug" on IE and I am new to this I don't know how to set the proper encoding, do you have any tutorials in  mind or something more clear ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+apply+proper+URL+encoding+to+a+value+in+javascript